# Banking System console app in C++

Tags: c++, security, repository

I built a banking system in C++ (still a lot of features to do but (I decided to post it here to see what can I change so I wont make those mistakes in the future).
**User header and c++ files**
*Header*

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class User
{

private:
    int id;
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    std::string balance;

public:
    User(int id, std::string username, std::string &password, int balance);


    ~User();

    int GetId();

    std::string GetUsername();
};
```

*CPP*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "HashPassword.h"
#include "User.h"





    User::User(int uId, std::string uUsername, std::string& uPassword, int uBalance)
    {
        id = uId;
        username = uUsername;
        password = uPassword;
        HashPassword(password);
        std::cout << password << '\n';
        balance = uBalance;
        std::cout << balance << '\n';
    }

    
    
    User::~User()
    {
    }

    int User::GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    std::string User::GetUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }
```

all of this is pretty easy to understand (I hope) but a couple of point: first of all the HashPassword method will be posted here so scroll down a bit for the implementation, but basically I used the picosha2 header file I got from GitHub and it does some magic I don't understand and hashes a string using sha256 algorithm.
second point I got a weird feeling about how I use pointers and pass by reference here so I would like some directions on that topic.

**HashPassword**

```
#include "HashPassword.h"


void HashPassword(std::string& password)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> hash(picosha2::k_digest_size);
    picosha2::hash256(password.begin(), password.end(), hash.begin(), hash.end());

    password = picosha2::bytes_to_hex_string(hash.begin(), hash.end());


}
```

this is my hashing process I took straight from the GitHub example and I have a broad idea on how it works but I don't understand it deeply.
my main concern here is the use of pointers and references.

**UserRepository**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "User.h"

class UserRepository
{
private:
    std::vector<User> userRepo;


public:
    UserRepository()
    {

    }
    ~UserRepository(){}

    void AddUser(std::string& username, std::string &password, int& balance)
    {
        
        int id = userRepo.size() + 1;
        User user(id, username, password, balance);
        userRepo.push_back(user);

    }


    void PrintAllUsers()
    {
        for(User user : userRepo)
        {
            std::cout << user.GetUsername() << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    User* FindUserByUsername(std::string username)
    {
        for (User user : userRepo)
        {
            if (user.GetUsername() == username)
            {
                User* p_user = &user;
                return p_user;
            }
        }

        return NULL;
    }
};
```

Here im using a vector as a repository that, and I just add users to it via AddUser and the id gets generated automatically based on how many users there are so if there are 7 users and another one joins then his id will be 8.
and this is it for now, working on adding authentication process and changing the way I go about using pointers and references.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you want to make changes and get a review on the updated code please ask a follow up question with a link back to this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Preface: Code reviews can happen on different levels. Others have already pointed out many of the issues regarding potential bugs, syntax, stylistic choices and idiomatic use of the language. This answer tries to review the code regarding the overall design and fit to the (implied) "requirements", especially as the question starts with

> (still a lot of features to do but (I decided to post it here to see what can I change so I wont make those mistakes in the future).

Given you are implementing a "banking system", it is a bit unexpected to see "user" as the first thing to implement. I would expect domain terms like "customer" and "(bank) account" to be reflected in the code first. Your `User` class seems to model kind of both, but it also focuses on the "less important" aspects of the domain. It is currently concerned mainly with the aspects of authenticating a user via a basic username/password combination (it actually does not implement that yet, but I assume this is your intent). It does have a "balance", which would cover the "account" aspect to a very limited degree.

I would recommend to start with a proper analysis of the domain and come up with a design where each domain concept is represented separately in your code and also that the various operations and processes that need to happen in your banking system are also explicitly represented and potentially separated.

Based on my simplistic understanding of a "bank", you would have at least:

- A `Customer` class, which represents a single customer of your bank. That typically includes name and contact/address information as well as a customer number/ID for internal references. It likely will have additional administrative information like when they first became a customer or if they are still an active customer or not (maybe you have to delete/anonymize personal data after a certain time?). *A customer does not have a password or a balance, as these are separate concepts and concerns.*
- A `Account` class, which represents a bank account which belongs to one (or many?) customer. It would have an account number and provides the operations to compute its balance, put money into it, withdraw money or transfer money from one account to another (possibly to/from another bank?) and most importantly, list all transactions which took place on it (may need to be limited at some point?). This already indicates that it cannot just store a simple balance, but that it needs to store "transactions" which happen over time. So, we also need...
- A `Transaction` class. This would hold information about what amount of money was transferred between which accounts by whom and when. Typically, transactions are immutable and the list of transactions on an account is "append-only".

Based on that you would then have some kind of repositories to manage all of your customers and accounts. That is similar to what you have with the `UserRepository` already. As your entities have a primary key (customer number or account number), it would make sense to use a `std::map` to get a fast lookup of those by that key. If you want to search customers by their name or other attributes, that would be implemented in additional methods. I would strongly suggest to not have functionality like `printAllUsers` in there. Instead the repository only provides the access methods to get an iterator for users/accounts/customers/... and implement the user interface related functionality elsewhere (*the same applies to the "entity" classes themselves too!*).

At this point, you have to think about where the business constraints and rules can be implemented. For example, where do you check if a transaction should actually be carried out on an account? You may need to put those into additional classes/functions as they operate on a higher level and a single entity.

Another thing to think about how it can be modeled/represented in your system is the fact that banks usually do not exist in isolation, but (have to) allow transferring money to and from other banks.

Only then would you start to model aspects of an "online banking system", which would then have things like "users" with authentication related information. There, it would in this day and age also be more likely that the authentication part is not a simple username/password combination, but possibly some sort of MFA. In addition, you would have to think about how individual *transactions* are authorized by the user (in the old days, this was done with pre-generated TAN lists, nowadays it would be some kind of "OTP token" system).

Of course, as this project is likely just an excercise and/or for fun, many points can be left out and shortened to reduce the overall scope. E.g. only allowing transactions within the bank and only providing username/password authentication.

Comment: A note on 1-N / N-N relationships: while an account may belong to multiple customers, a single customer is quite likely to have several accounts. Also, it may be interesting to start looking at polymorphism: there are different kinds of accounts -- think regular account, savings account, escrow accounts (oh, multiple customers!) -- and this may be modeled in various ways.

Comment: @MatthieuM. good points. I would be careful with polymorphism though as that is diffcult to get right (but may be a good excercise then).

Comment: A thing I also contemplated was that transactions probably exist outside of an account and only reference them in some way. It is not a single account a transaction is attached to, but two. The account then may provide methods to manage transactions from its perspective, but for example a transfer between two accounts would show up on both accounts. This is also an opportunity to think about how to ensure atomic operations and consistency (i.e. no money is lost or duplicated).

Answer (score 12):

#### Please Provide Complete Code

This sample doesn’t compile, because `"hashpassword.h"` is missing (and seems to rely on an external `picosha` library.)

#### Use the Correct Types

You properly are using signed fixed-point math for balances.  (At least, that’s what I assume you’re doing; you never document what units the balance is being stored in.)  However, you overuse `int` here.  On some platforms, that’s only 16 bits wide (one of which is the sign bit).  If a bank needs to track fractions of a cent for correct rounding, even 31 value bits will overflow for a balance in the seven figures, which could realistically happen.

I would therefore recommend `int_least64_t` from `<cstdint>`.  If you really, truly want something that’s short, simple and at least 32 bits wide, though, at least use `long`.  You might also want a declaration similar to

```
using Balance = std::int_least64_t;
```

This makes it feasible to change the type of a bank balance later.

Another place where you shouldn’t be using `int` is:

```
int id = userRepo.size() + 1;
```

The size will be a `size_t`, which can overflow an `int` (in as few as 32,767 accounts on some implementations).  Prior to C++23, this would be undefined behavior, which compilers today interpret as permission to silently introduce security bugs.  In C++23, it will yield duplicate user IDs.  Granted, you might be confident that your bank will never run this software on 16-bit CPUs and never sign up a quarter of the world’s population as customers.  But still, on principle, use `size_t` or some big-enough unsigned counter for your account IDs.

This is one of a few things that makes me suspect you learned C# first.  In C#, `Int` is exactly 32 bits wide.  In C++, `int` is a type that we dinosaurs rarely use, because we remember the ’90s, when it was different sizes on different machines.

#### Avoid Global Variables

At present, you have a single `userRepo` global variable.  Passing a `Repo&` to every function in the program (the Tramp Data pattern) might not be an improvement, but you should consider it if only because it gives you the flexibility to maintain multiple smaller repos that can be searched separately, for instance if you later acquire another bank or open a second branch.

#### Use Consistent Naming Patterns

You’re declaring your member functions in PascalCase, but variables in camelCase.  This is common in C#, but it’s much more common in C++ to use PascalCase for class names and camelCase for class members.  The other common convention is snake_case for everything.

#### Password Security

You appear to be storing the SHA-256 hash of the password, presumably to protect your passwords from someone with a copy of the database.  This is vulnerable to dictionary or rainbow-table attacks, which compute the hashes of commonly-used passwords.

Without going into the weeds of all the things people might do to improve security, one very common technique to defend against this is to add a password “salt.”  That is, you randomly generate a few extra bytes such as `\xA4\x2B\x76\xAF`, different for each user, so that if the user chooses the password `asdfghjk`, you actually compute the hash of something like `asdfghjk\xA4\x2B\x76\xAF` or the XOR with `0xA42B76AF`.  This means an attacker can no longer just search your database for the hashes of `password`, `qwertyuiop`, and so on.  Since the salts are stored in the database along with the hashes, an attacker can still pick an account, see its salt, then try a rainbow-table attack on that one account.  Another common technique is to add “pepper.”  That is, pick a secret value to modify all the hashes, and don’t store it in the same files as the salts or hashes.  That way, an attacker can only guess at the passwords of your dumb rich clients if they also obtain your source code, or put a lot of work into reverse-engineering the executable.

I don’t get the impression that robust security is the focus of this exercise, but since you asked for a review of the security code, that’s where I’d start.

Comment: thanks for the pointers (haha get it) I edited my code, haven't got around renaming my variables in according to C++ conventions but I will do it, also Ill add salting at some point, I hope this version of the code is better.
also I did start with C# then moved to java and now settled at C++.

Comment: @Guy No problem. In that case, one other piece of advice: in C#, one of your most useful tools is LINQ. You can get the same functionality in C++ by templating functions such as your search to take a `std::ranges::range`, which you can then pass some view, such as filtering on a predicate, searching a subrange of IDs, or transforming the balance from dollars to euros.

Comment: Regarding password security, there might also be some issues to discuss related to making sure that any clear-text copy of the password is stored in memory that's protected from being pushed out to swap, and then cleared from memory as soon as possible.  (Though that's likely to involve some advanced C++ coding which in parts will necessarily be platform-dependent -- unless maybe you use some library such as OpenSSL which already has handling for such issues, and then create C++ wrappers around that.)

Answer (score 7):

```
User(int id, std::string username, std::string &password, int balance)
```

Passing the username by value will most probably create an unnecessary copy of the string. The preferable way to pass it is by `const&` or if used in modern C++ (17+) std::string_view.

In this function's implementation you used different names for the arguments than in the declaration. The reason is to avoid the mention of `this` when assigning the variables.

You can use different conventions to avoid that like naming class variables with `m_variableName`, and this way you can avoid strange naming in the parameters.

Another possible way in this case is to use initialization list:

```
User::User(int id, std::string username, std::string& password, int balance)
          : id(id), username(username), password(HashPassword(password)), balance(balance)
{
    std::cout << this->password << '\n';
    std::cout << this->balance << '\n';
}
```

Pay attention that some places won't like the idea of calling a function from the initialization list (like HasPassword), for reasons like debug friendly code, but I personally don't agree with that argument.

For your `GetUsername` function, you might want to consider returning a std::string_view or `const std::string&` instead, for performance issues.

For your `HashPassword` function, it might be better for this function to return a std::string of the hashed password, instead of modifying the original one. This function is more like a library function, and the standard usually doesn't modify the argument in these cases.

```
User user(id, username, password, balance);
userRepo.push_back(user);
```

Now here it's a classic case to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`, because in this case you actually use 2 constructors for User. One that you can see explicitly, and another one to copy the User instance to the push_back call / for the insertion to the vector. When using emplace_back you can use one constructor instead:

```
userRepo.emplace_back(id, username, password, balance);

void PrintAllUsers()
{
    for(User user : userRepo)
    {
        std::cout << user.GetUsername() << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

In this function, it's better to iterate over userRepo with `const User&` to avoid copies of all the users. This way you will iterate using pointers instead, which is much cheaper in this case.

```
User* FindUserByUsername(std::string username)
{
    for (User user : userRepo)
    {
        if (user.GetUsername() == username)
        {
            User* p_user = &user;
            return p_user;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

In this function I want to talk about several things.

1. You can pass as argument `const std::string&` (or `std::string_view` since C++17).
2. Same issue of iterating with `const&` instead by value.
3. Your intention was to return a pointer from the vector, and I want to talk about the issues in your intentions before talking about the actual thing that happens here.

When returning a pointer from the vector, you expose yourself to the risk of `iterator invalidation`, and you actually break the encapsulation of the users that are being stored inside the class. It might be better to return a copy or `const User&`, depends if performance are in demand here.

However, that's not the actual case here. Because you iterate over your vector by value, you actually return a pointer to the temporary variable in the loop. Which means, that you return a pointer to an address that you don't have access outside of the loop scope. This is a bug.

4. There is no need for the line `User* p_user = &user;`, you can simply use `return &user`.
5. When returning a null, use `nullptr` keyword instead of the C macro NULL.

Comment: On the first observation, note that we are making a copy of the `username` string, so the best fix is `User::User(std::string username) : username{std::move(username)}`.  This avoids unnecessary copies in the most situations.

Comment: Lots of good points on the loop variables, but as mentioned by Toby that first point on not passing by values is strangely at odds with the otherwise modern recommendations...

Comment: @TobySpeight you actually don't avoid copies in your example, because you copy the string into the function. If you want to use move semantics you have to pass std::string&& to the function, but it depends if you have any usage of that username outside of the function. I don't know which way is better, because I don't think there is an absolute better way.

Comment: Nope, pass-by-value should avoid unnecessary copy when we call with an rvalue (e.g. `User{std::string{"name"}}`¹) or with an rvalue reference (e.g. `User{std::move(name)}`), since the argument is then move-constructed.  Only lvalue references actually get copied, and that's obviously unavoidable as both original and destination need to exist and be distinct afterwards.   (N.B. ¹ I'm omitting other arguments for clarity)

Answer (score 4):

A banking system will inevitably require some level of concurrency, and your method of deriving the User id is not thread safe. Two (or more) threads could check the size of the userRepo at the same time, and then generate the same ID.